# ¿Comó poder implementar esto en javafx?

Tags: java-swing, javafx

La intención del siguiente código es que pueda conectar a una cámara IP por medio rtsp en `javafx`, pero javafx no soporta este protocolo y ya he intentado hacerlo usando scene media y no logro que funcione. ¿seria posible mostrar esto con algún complemento de `javafx`, pensé en usar `ImageView`.

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

/**
 *
 * @author JLAM
 */
public class JavaCv {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
OpenCVFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber("rtsp://admin:Guatex2018!@10.10.11.237/Streaming/Channels/2");

    introducir el código aquí
    frameGrabber.setFormat("h.264");

    frameGrabber.start();

    IplImage iPimg = frameGrabber.grab();
    CanvasFrame canvasFrame = new CanvasFrame("Camara");
    canvasFrame.setCanvasSize(iPimg.width(), iPimg.height());

    while (canvasFrame.isVisible() && (iPimg = frameGrabber.grab()) != null) {
        canvasFrame.showImage(iPimg);
    }
    frameGrabber.stop();
    canvasFrame.dispose();
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un MediaView con el cual soporta bastantes formatos de video e incluso Streaming de video. Te dejo un tutorial simple donde se puede ver su funcionamiento, te recomiendo leerlo al pie de la letra y asi ver todas sus caracteristicas. 
A modo de ejemplo te dejo el siguiente fragmento de codigo:

```
Media media = new Media("PATH_RESOURCE Ó URL_STREAMING");
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
// create mediaView and add media player to the viewer
MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer); 
((Group)scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(mediaView);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm